# Generar Options con array estaticos PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Tengo un archivo php (data.php) donde almaceno en array informacion que muy pocas veces se va a cambiar (medios de pago,modalidades de ventas, etc)
Esta es la estructura:

```
$medios_de_pago=array(
    "1"=>"Efectivo",
    "2"=>"Tarjeta de credito/debito"
);

$modalidad_de_pedidos=array(
    "1"=>"Local",
    "2"=>"Delivery"
);
```

si hago esto es porque se que estos datos no van a cambiar y guardarlo en una base de datos seria mas consumo de recursos y consultas innecesarias.

Ahora bien, yo quiero crear una funcion que me recorrar tanto `$medios_de_pago` como `$modalidad_de_pedidos` y me genere `<option value='id'>elemento</option>`
De antemano agradesco su ayuda.

***NOTAS: si existe una mejor manera de almacenar esta informacion me la comentan nada mas yo estoy abierto a opiniones, quizas un json o algo asi.***

**EDITADO:**
PROVE CON ESTO:

```
foreach ($medios_de_pago as $key => $vd) {
    var_export($key)."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Ok, que has intentado? Por otro lado el option debe tener los datos de que array?

Comment: con respecto a lo que e intentado ya edite mi pregunta, ahora bien los option deben tener los datos de cualquier array, la cosa es poder recorrerlos, por ejemplo la funcion seria asi:

options($tipo){
if($tipo=="medios_de_pago"){...}
if($tipo=="modalidad_de_pedidos"){...}

}

cosa que segun lo que pongo como parametro me va a leer el array correspondiente.

Comment: si sabes que va a cambiar tan pocas veces, por que no haces directamente todo el html en ese archivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si he entendido bien tu comentario:

*`la cosa es poder recorrerlos, por ejemplo la funcion seria asi: options($tipo){ if($tipo=="medios_de_pago"){...} if($tipo=="modalidad_de_pedidos"){...} } cosa que segun lo que pongo como parametro me va a leer el array correspondiente`*

Entonces podrías tener un sólo array asociativo en el cual pones una clave para los parámetros `medios_de_pago`, `modalidad_de_pedidos` y otros.

Hablamos de una estructura como esta:

```
$mData=array (
                "medios_de_pago"=> 
                    array(
                            "1"=>"Efectivo",
                            "2"=>"Tarjeta de credito/debito"
                        ),
    
                "modalidad_de_pedidos"=>
                    array(
                            "1"=>"Local",
                            "2"=>"Delivery"
                    )
             );
```

Si observas bien, las claves de cada sub-array contienen los datos correspondientes a cada tipo.

Propongo una función como esta, donde se incluye un control en caso de que el tipo buscado no exista en el array. En ese caso, se creará un option con valor `-1`, esto lo puedes cambiar por lo que más te convenga.

Esta sería la función:

```
function showOptions($param) {
    $mData=array (
                    "medios_de_pago"=> 
                        array(
                                "1"=>"Efectivo",
                                "2"=>"Tarjeta de credito/debito"
                            ),

                    "modalidad_de_pedidos"=>
                        array(
                                "1"=>"Local",
                                "2"=>"Delivery"
                        )
                 );
    #Variable para concatenar
    $mOptions="";
    #Verificamos si $param existe en el $mData
    if (array_key_exists($param,$mData)){
        #Si existe lo leeemos
        foreach ($mData[$param] as $k=>$v){
            $mOptions.="<option value=\"$k\">$v</option>";
        }
    #Si no existe, creamos una opción por defecto    
    }else{
            $mOptions.="<option value=\"-1\">No existe $param</option>";
    }
    #Retornamos el resultado
    return $mOptions;
}
```

Hagamos varias pruebas:

```
echo showOptions("medios_de_pago");
```

**Salida:**

```
<option value="1">Efectivo</option>
<option value="2">Tarjeta de credito/debito</option>
```

---

```
echo showOptions("fake");
```

**Salida:**

```
<option value="-1">No existe fake</option>
```

---

```
echo showOptions("modalidad_de_pedidos");
```

**Salida:**

```
<option value="1">Local</option>
<option value="2">Delivery</option>
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfeccion, es lo que buscaba; gracias por la ayuda crack ;) !